# How to update a specific element in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I created a data table consist of student record using material UI. There is a different student array for each row. There is a fee verification button pushed in each student array. I want to change the status of fee on button click but instead the status of whole table is changing. I applied some methods to pick the student ID when clicked but none of them is working. Here is my code in which both arrays are creating.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// core components
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";
import VerifyButton from "components/MyButtons/VerifyButton";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function TableList() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  var [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  var result = [];
  var name = "";
  var fatherName = "";
  var contactNo = "";
  var email = "";
  var group = "";
  var button;
  var gender = "";

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        API_KEY
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
      console.log(isLoading);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
 
  for (var i in data) {
    const id = "Student" + i;
    name = data[i].name;
    fatherName = data[i].father_name;
    contactNo = "0" + "" + data[i].contact_no;
    group = data[i].group;
    email = data[i].youremail;
    button = <VerifyButton verify={verified} onVerify={verifyPayment} />;
    var student = [];
    student.push(name);
    student.push(fatherName);
    //student.push(contactNo);
    student.push(group);
    //student.push(email);
    student.push(button);
    student.push(verified);
    student.push(id);
    console.log(student);
    result.push(student);
  }

  function verifyPayment() {
    // const elementIndex = student.findIndex((element) => element.id == id);
    // let newData = [...std];
    // newData[elementIndex] = {
    //   ...newData[elementIndex],
    //   verified: !newData[elementIndex].verified,
    // };
    setVerified(true);
  }

  console.log(result);
  console.log(tableDat);

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader color="primary">
            <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Classes Data</h4>
            <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
              Here is the data for the crash classes
            </p>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Table
              tableHeaderColor="primary"
              tableHead={[
                "Name",
                "Father Name",
                "Contact No",
                "Group",
                "Email",
              ]}
              tableData={result}
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is also the image of the table creating
[image: table]
Red buttons are the fee status buttons. Right now they are all updating when any button clicked
If somebody from the community will help me, i will be eternally grateful.

Comment: Can u please show the structure of `student` how it looks like? Also if u can add few more details like what `setVerified` does. And explain what u want to do with an example if possible.

Comment: Student is a simple array like [name, contactno ....] setverified is a flag which sets fee verification status. I am updating my question with my full code. I want to update the fee verification status of each student on button click.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the modification of your code, I would make the following changes :

- get rid of the global verified state
- making result a state of TableList, initialized with []
- passing throught onVerify the index of the line your record is
- updating the result state in the onVerify  function to trigger a rerender

As I understand it, this is a local project, because the checked values are not persisted in a database. This would change the code significantly

I have not run this code, but it should be something like this

```
...

export default function TableList() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  var name = "";
  var fatherName = "";
  var contactNo = "";
  var email = "";
  var group = "";
  var button;
  var gender = "";

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_KEY);
      const json = await response.json();
      const newResult = []
      for (const i in json) {
        const id = "Student" + i;
        name = data[i].name;
        fatherName = data[i].father_name;
        contactNo = "0" + "" + data[i].contact_no;
        group = data[i].group;
        email = data[i].youremail;
        button = <VerifyButton verify={verified} onVerify={() => verifyPayment(i)} />;
        var student = [];
        student.push(name);
        student.push(fatherName);
        //student.push(contactNo);
        student.push(group);
        //student.push(email);
        student.push(button);
        student.push(verified);
        student.push(id);
        console.log(student);
        newResult.push(student);
      }
      setResult(newResult)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
 
  
  function verifyPayment(index) {
    const updatedStudent = result[index] // Extract the record to update
    updatedStudent[4] = true //verified
    setResult(
      [
        ...result.slice(0, index),
        updatedStudent,
        ...result.slice(index+1)
      ]
    ) // Rebuild the array of student with all students that have not change and with the updated record 
  }

...
```

Comment: Can you please define it a little bit more.

Comment: I just want to understand, if you are removing data, then where in which array json should saved? And in the verify payment method what is newStudent[4]?

Comment: I think you should keep reading about state management in a react component, it will benefit you. 
For the global verified state, you can't use it because you have separate verified status for each student, so you need to maintain n status for n students.
I have updated my answer to add some comments

Comment: For the result of your API, you don't need it either because you only use it once at the initialization of your component. You should only keep in your state the value which can trigger a rerendering of your component when a change occure. In your case that would be an array of student, and each time a property of one student change (as the verified status) you want to rerender your array to display that change.